# environment variables in Docker images in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm working on some GCP apps which are dockerized in a Kubernetes cluster in GCP (I'm new to Docker and Kubernetes). In order to access some of the GCP services, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS needs to point to a credentials file.
 
**Should the environment variable be set and that file included in:
 
- each of the Docker images?

- the Kubernetes cluster?**

**GCP specific stuff**
This is the actual error: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

**-Should the environment variable be set and that file included in:
 
- each of the Compute Engine instances? 
- the main GCP console?**

And, most importantly, HOW? 
:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a service account (IAM & Admin > Service Accounts), generate a key for it in JSON format and then give it the needed permissions (IAM & Admin > IAM). If your containers need access to this, it's best practice to add it as a secret in kubernetes and mount it in your containers. Then set the environment variable to point to the secret which you've mounted:

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH_TO_SECRET]"

This page should get you going:  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#step_4_import_credentials_as_a_secret